# Function Not Defined Error Inside HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get my facebook posts using the facebook graph api.But due to variation of likes,comment,share key in json data I had to make a function that could handle the cases.But when I'm trying to call the function in the html code below it shows function undefined errror.Can anyone please help me!!

```
function getPostsFacebookInfo(){
$.ajax('https://graph.facebook.com/me/posts?access_token='+myFacebookToken,{

    success : function(response){
        $.each(response.data,function(index,response){
            console.log(response);
            var react=function (){
                        if(response.hasOwnProperty('likes'))
                        {   
                            $('#reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Likes:${response.likes.data.length}</li>`);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(' #reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Likes:0</li>`);
                        }

                        if(response.hasOwnProperty('comments'))
                        {   
                            $('#reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Comments:${response.comments.data.length}</li>`);

                        }else
                        {
                            $('#reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Comments:0</li>`);
                        }

                        if(response.hasOwnProperty('shares'))
                        {   
                            $('#reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Shares:${response.shares.data.length}</li>`);

                        }else
                        {
                            $('#reactions').append(`<li class="list-group-item">Shares:0</li>`);
                        }
                };
            $('#panelbody').append(`
                <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <p>${response.message}</p>
                <img src="${response.picture}" class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3" id="reactions">
                    <script>react();</script>//function call here..
                </div>
                </div> 
                </div>`);
            //end argument list 
        });
    }
  });// end ajax call 

}// end get facebook info


getBasicFacebookInfo();
getPostsFacebookInfo();
```

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Can you please explain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting You need to escape the message.  You should use a data-binding system or templating engine.

Comment: Is there any other easy way to do this.Actually I'm trying to display the no. of likes,comments,shares along with the posts inside a bootstrap well by appending.Can u please tell how to achieve this.

Comment: Your function Is defined in the scope of the each callback, not globally. It needs to be global if executed the way you want in a script tag.

Comment: I tried by keeping the react function outside the document ready function but still getting error as response not defined though I passed response as a parameter while calling the function.Please can u give me the working code @ste2425

Comment: @Rahuljhawar: Using a templating engine _is_ the easy way.  Building HTML by hand will lead to a world of pain.

Comment: _"Please can [yo]**u** give me the working code"_ -- Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  _"it shows function undefined errror"_ -- You don't even tell us **what** function it says is undefined... Copy and paste the _actual_ error message into your question.  Don't retype it, that just leads to mistakes.  And see [ask] in the help center.

Comment: Thank You @StephenP. I will surely go through it.By the way the problem is solved.But I have a doubt--- I have 2 html files and 1 js file for both.In the 1st html file a form will be submitted in which facebook token will be submitted.I want to store the token in a variable and with the variable value carry out the ajax requests accordingly and display the data using templating engine in the 2nd html file.I'm able to display the data by directly providing the facebooktoken to a variable.Can u give me an idea how the former functionality can be achieved.Thanks in advance!